# Python tkinter how to display an image in real time?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6

When I try to display an image from my disc without downloading it from internet, all works good and an image is displayed correctly. But when I try to download an image from my site, change its extension to .gif in order to work with PIL library, and display it after clicking a button, nothing is display. I'm sure that all operations in `subprocess.call` are performed correctly. How can I make it work?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
root.title("My app")
root.geometry("680x500+0+0")

def callback(event):
    subprocess.call("wget example.com/pic.png && mv pic.png pic.gif", shell = True)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("pic.gif"))
    la.configure(image = img)

b1 = Button(root, text = "b1", bg = "red")
b1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

b2 = Button(root, text = "b2", bg = "blue")
b2.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

la = Label(root, text="hi")
la.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

b2.bind("<Button-1>", callback)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: png and gif are different formats.
You might consider converting png to gif using for instance ImageMagick.

Comment: You will have to save the image before loading it to your app. Also PIL can handle png just fine. Here is a [list of supported formats](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html).

Comment: You can't just change the extension and have the file magically be converted to a different format.

Comment: you can't change extension .png to .gif to get GIF file - you would have to use program to convert it. But `Image.open` can load PNG file so you don't have to convert.

Comment: PL: zmiana rozszerzenia .png na .gif nie zamienia pliku na GIF - musiałbyś użyć jakiegoś programu do konwersji. Ale `Image.open` potrafi wczytać PNG więc nie musisz konwertować.

Comment: you can use `Button( ..., command=callback)` and `def callback():` without `event`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:** you can't change extension `.png` to `.gif` to get GIF file. You would have to use some program to convert it. But `Image.open` can works with PNG files so you don't have to convert it.

```
 img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("furas.png"))
```

**Second:** there is bug in `PhotoImage` which removes image from memory when it is assigned to local variable in function. So you have to assign it to global variable. Common method is assigning it to label which will display it. You can use any name for variable - ie. `.image`

```
 la.image = img
```

More in documentation: [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) on effbot.org

**Third:** did you run code in terminal to see error messages ? You forgot to import `subprocess`

Full code with existing image

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import subprocess

def callback(event):
    subprocess.call("wget https://blog.furas.pl/theme/images/me/furas.png", shell=True)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("furas.png"))
    la.configure(image=img)
    la.image = img

root = Tk()
root.title("My app")
root.geometry("680x500+0+0")

b1 = Button(root, text="b1", bg="red")
b1.grid(row=0, column=0)

b2 = Button(root, text="b2", bg="blue")
b2.grid(row=0, column=1)

la = Label(root, text="hi")
la.grid(row=1, column=0)

b2.bind("<Button-1>", callback)

root.mainloop()
```

**BTW:** you can use `Button(..., command=callback)` but remove `event` from `def callback()`

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import subprocess

def callback():
    subprocess.call("wget https://blog.furas.pl/theme/images/me/furas.png", shell=True)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("furas.png"))
    la.configure(image=img)
    la.image = img

root = Tk()
root.title("My app")
root.geometry("680x500+0+0")

b1 = Button(root, text="b1", bg="red")
b1.grid(row=0, column=0)

b2 = Button(root, text="b2", bg="blue", command=callback)
b2.grid(row=0, column=1)

la = Label(root, text="hi")
la.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

**EDIT:** instead of `wget` you can use Python's standard module `urllib` and function `urllib.request.urlretrive()`

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import urllib.request

def callback():
    urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://blog.furas.pl/theme/images/me/furas.png", "furas.png")
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("furas.png"))
    la.configure(image=img)
    la.image = img

root = Tk()
root.title("My app")
root.geometry("680x500+0+0")

b1 = Button(root, text="b1", bg="red")
b1.grid(row=0, column=0)

b2 = Button(root, text="b2", bg="blue", command=callback)
b2.grid(row=0, column=1)

la = Label(root, text="hi")
la.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```